# Node Js with Postgres. Row Count is 2 but row contents are shown as undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql

NodeJS has to retrieve the value of the email address column of each row from the table in the database. The table currently has two rows in it. The query works on pgAdmin.I am running the following piece of code to achieve this. I have omitted the error handling code here to simplify my example.

```
client.query("SELECT email_address AS emailAddress" +
            " FROM pgi.donor_information"
            , function(err, result) {
                var rowCount = result.rows.length;
                console.log("Row count: %d",rowCount);
                for(var i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i){
                    console.log(result.rows[i].emailAddress);
                }
            });
```

The output received is

```
Row count: 2
undefined
undefined
```

Why is the emailAddress field in each row shown as undefined. I'm a newbie to node js, so please dont downvote this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because PostgreSQL flattens camel cases, so your `emailAddress` arrives as `emailaddress`, unless the column name is enforced with `""`, i.e. if you change `AS emailAddress` in your query to `AS "emailAddress"`, then it will work as you wanted.